# How to rename a file into a random GUID?

Tags: shell, rename

The task is to replace a file's (actually of all the files in a directory) name (but leave extension intact) with a random UUID/GUID. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Similar to bahamat answer, but generates actual [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID). UUIDs have some reserved bits that are used to determine the version and variant used. There are currently 5 types of UUIDs defined, random UUIDs, as you asked, are version 4. You will note that version 4 UUIDs have this format:

```
442b7f35-f33f-4b8d-9a07-db8ec207129e
              |    '-- variant (bits 10__ -> [89AB])
              '------- version (bits 0100 -> 4)
```

Also, this version doesn't cause damage in case the UUID generation fails.

```
for i in *; do uuid=$(uuidgen -r) && mv -- "$i" "$uuid.${i##*.}"; done
```

for macOS

```
for i in *; do uuid=$(uuidgen) && mv -- "$i" "$uuid.${i##*.}"; done
```

Using */proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid*:

```
for i in *; do uuid=$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid) && mv -- "$i" "$uuid.${i##*.}" done
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
for i in *; do mv -- "$i" "$(openssl rand -hex 16).${i##*.}"; done
```

Using `openssl rand 16` gives you 128 bit GUIDs. Use 32 if you want 256 bit GUIDs.

Comment: If you have it, `uuidgen` works too (sys-apps/util-linux in Gentoo)

Comment: UUIDs are *not* completely random. Random UUIDs are version 4 UUIDs, and have only 122 random bits, not 128. The fixed bits define the version (4) and variant of the UUID. You should use either `uuidgen` or `/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid` to generate UUIDs.

Answer (score 2):

Short Perl script below - the use of *cat* to get the uuid isn't the cleanest/fastest way to code it, but it keeps the command short:

```
perl -e '
  foreach (@ARGV) {
    my $uid=qx|cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid|;
    chomp $uid;
    (my $new=$_)=~s#(.*)\.#$uid.#;
    rename($_, $new)
  }
' ./*.file_ext
```

The above uses a file in /proc on linux as a source of uuids:

```
[bash#] cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid
d474706f-b18c-4e4b-8762-5ed577c74ac3
```

Comment: `ls` output is not meant to be parsed. `ls` is meant to produce user-readable output, and it may substitute characters in filenames.

Comment: @Juliano Point taken - but using a shell glob "*.file_ext" risks an "argument list too long error", whereas the error risks from "\ls -1 | pipeline..." are minimal - it's a more pragmatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux:

```
(ret=0
for file in *; do
  IFS= read -r uuid < /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid || exit
  mv -i -- "$file" "$uuid" || ret=$?
done
exit "$ret")
```